# Two sided WCF services communication

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I'm using WCF.

I have two applications: "Main" and "Worker".

Sometimes application "Main" is giving task for "Worker".
"Worker" is doing work and when work is done it gives result to "Main".

How should this communication be done?

I need to call Worker.AddTask(Task) from Main and Main.AddResult(Result) from Worker.
Is there better way than setting up two Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds classic for WCF's callbacks- it allows for two-way async communication between server and client (in your case, the server would be the 'worker', and the 'main' application would invoke its methods in order to start processing. When worker is done, it will invoke a callback on main.)
[LMGTFY](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=wcf%20callback&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) :)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for stupid question. I didn't think about it as callback (I have never work with callback through net)

Comment: me neither :). and don't think your question is stupid; until I asked the same question myself, I've never heard of that feature too :)

Answer (score 2):

Does every call to "Worker" eventually end with a result for "Main" to work with? If so, you might want to just have "Main" call "Worker" asynchronously, the "Main" can just wait for the results as then come back. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two applications are separate processes and communicating over services...

I think you may use [netTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx) and [Callback contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This requires two way communication between the two components.  The first link I'm providing is the description in MSDN and the second link points to an implementation example.  Enjoy.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752264.aspx)

[Example Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/835e7704-55f3-4357-9806-fc938763ae93)